# Unable to retrieve data from Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am running a jupyter notebook with spark.

I tried do the this script below:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "xxxx")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "uyuu")
df = sql_context.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://xxxx") \
    .option("dbtable", "index") \
    .option('forward_spark_s3_credentials',True) \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://xxxx/temp") \
    .load()

print(df)
```

It worked and was able to print me the column details of my data in redshift. However, I wanted to access the data and hence did df.show().

However, this error returned back to me

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.showString.
>       : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eclipsesource/json/Json

Can I know what am I doing wrong possibly?

PS: these are the steps which I have taken:

1. I have placed these jar files into my hadoop spark jar folder:

   spark-redshift_2.10-3.0.0-preview1.jar
   RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar
   hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar
   aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
   aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.60.jar
2. I ran pyspark which initiates the jupyter notebook localhost
3. I ran the script above
4. Error trace logs

> ---> 10 print(df.show())

```
C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    348         """
    349         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 350             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    351         else:
    352             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.showString.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eclipsesource/json/Json
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.buildScan(RedshiftRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
```

Comment: Can you please add this information: 1. the full stack trace, 2. how you packaged and ran your application 3. how you added the dependencies related to your data source (redshift).

Comment: Hi Ernest, Please see above. I have supplemented more details

Comment: You added `spark-redshift_2.10:3.0.0-preview` static jar, but this jar does require compile dependencies, which are missing on your runtime (one of these being `com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:0.9.4`). It's safer to add the dependency by passing the maven coordinates through `--packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:3.0.0-preview1`, which will collect the dependency as well as the transitive dependencies.

Comment: Hi Ernest, 

I have actually done this and realised i wasmissing minimal json. upgraded my preview to 2.11 and it is ok now

Comment: Hey @Adam Can you please tell me how you solved this error?